# No timezone in response

Tags: rest, here-api

I'm working with https://developer.here.com services and I'm trying to get the timezone on reverse gecoding, like this:

https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=47.2094,8.6908%2C250&mode=retrieveAreas&maxresults=1&level=city&**locationattributes=timeZone**&gen=8&app_id={mymappid}&app_code={myappcode}

I got everything back I need, just no timezone. The response result with or without 'locationattributes=timeZone' doesn't differ. Is there anything I'm doing wrong based on the documentation at: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html ?

Answer (score 2):

In between I've found the solution:
Even tough 'timeZone' is accepted as parameter value and doesn't return anything I found out, that the parameter 'adminInfo' returns the timeZone as UTC abbreviation (and some more values):

Call:
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=47.2094,8.6908%2C250&mode=retrieveAreas&maxresults=1&level=city&**locationattributes=adminInfo**&gen=8&app_id={myappid}&app_code={myappcode}

Return:
... {**"TimeZoneOffset":"UTC+02:00"**,"LocalTime":"2018-05-01T15:23:03+0200", ...

Thats ok for my need.

Comment: I need the DST independent tz scheme like "Europe/Berlin". The response "UTC+0200" depends on the time of the call itself. I'd rather have a response that only depends on the prox coordinates...